# Is there a name for the 'break n' construct?

Tags: programming-languages, terminology, language-design, language-features

In a conversation earlier this week I was discussing certain language features, and I realized I don't have a good word / phrase to describe a particular feature.

Some languages, such as PHP, have a language construct which allows [`break`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) and [`continue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) statements to accept a numeric parameter indicating which block should be affected. For example:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    for ($j = 10; $j > 0; $j--)
        if ($j == $i) 
            break 2;
echo $i;
```

Because `break 2;` causes the outer loop to break, the output is `1`. If this were `break 1;` or just `break;` the output would be `10`.

C# does not have any such construct. The equivalent would something like this:

```cs
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    bool broken = false;
    for (j = 10; j > 0; j--) {
        if (j == i) {
            broken = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (broken)
        break;
}
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

<sup>But of course, this could also be accomplished using a `goto`.</sup>

So my question is, what do you call this? Is there a specific name for this "break *n*" construct? I'd like to be able to say "*Language X has parametric break and continue statements*", or something like that.

Comment: With php 5.4, the option for this to be a variable was removed.  Its no different than a label break in that respect now - just different syntax.  Label break is available in all languages that I am familiar with that have a break statement.

Comment: @MichaelT Hmm, I wasn't familiar with the "label-break" until you mentioned it. It seems Java supports it ([demo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/BreakWithLabelDemo.java)), but not C#.

Comment: C# does have a `goto` that can be used to skip out of nested loops - see [Breaking out of a nested loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324831/breaking-out-of-a-nested-loop) (and its not a language I'm familiar with)

Comment: @MichaelT Just a side note: it seems PHP doesn't support using labels, at least not with the same syntax that Java uses. I tried `outer: for(..) for(..) break outer;` and it appears that `break outer;` is the same as `break;`. But I agree that this is just a variation of the same idea.

Comment: I find `break` with a label name (where the label is, ideally, the *name* of the loop) to be much clearer than `break 2`. Having the *computer* require a *human* to count something is absurd.

Comment: This could be reformulated to an inner `while` loop, and I'd be willing to bet that PHP is the *only* language that has this construct.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know it's rare, but PHP is not the *only* one. After some quick Googling I found [this](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/basis/manual/node95.html) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-loop-control.htm), and I seem to remember seeing it elsewhere, too.

Comment: Well then.  How about "Break n" for a name, then?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, that's what I've been calling it. I was just curious to know if a more formal name existed, and I was hoping to draw on the enormous collective experience of the users on this site.

Comment: It's called spaguetti code

Comment: I called it multilevel break in a language I designed.

Comment: @MichaelT: Python doesn't have a labelled break statement.

Comment: @mipadi correct, again another language I'm not familiar with.  Searching on it, one finds [PEP 3136](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/) which was [rejected](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-July/008663.html) - "However, I'm rejecting it on the basis that code so complicated to require this feature is very rare." --- though I don't agree with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has this and it is called a "labelled break" from what I've seen.

From Oracle's [Java Tutorial on Branching Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html):

> The break statement has two forms: labeled and unlabeled. ... An unlabeled break statement terminates the innermost switch, for, while, or do-while statement, but a **labeled break** terminates an outer statement.

In your PHP example it's not really "labelled" per-se (although you could consider the `2` an implicit label) but more like a "relative" or "nested" break. Any of those adjectives should work.

---

PS - I'm surprised C# didn't steal that from Java since they took just about everything else.

Comment: C# took only the good things from Java  ;-)