# Does this justify goto statements?

Tags: coding-style, goto

I came across this question a second ago, and I'm pulling some of the material off of there: [Is there a name for the 'break n' construct?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227979/is-there-a-name-for-the-break-n-construct)

This appears to be a needlessly complex way for people to have to instruct the program to break out of a double-nested for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    bool broken = false;
    for (j = 10; j > 0; j--) {
        if (j == i) {
            broken = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (broken)
        break;
}
```

I know textbooks like to say goto statements are the devil, and I'm not fond of them at all myself, but does this justify an exception to the rule?

I'm looking for answers that deal with n-nested for loops.

**NOTE:** Whether you answer yes, no, or somewhere in between, completely close-minded answers are **not** welcome.  Especially if the answer is no, then provide a good, legitimate reason why (which is not too far from Stack Exchange regulations anyway).

Comment: If you can write the inner loop condition as `for (j = 10; j > 0 && !broken; j--)` then you wouldn't need the `break;` statement. If you move the declaration of `broken` to before the outer loop begins, then if that could be written as `for (i = 0; i < 10 && !broken; i++)` then I think *no* `break;`s are necessary.

Comment: Given the example is from C# - the C# reference on `goto`: [goto (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx) - "The goto statement is also useful to get out of deeply nested loops."

Comment: OMG, I never knew c# had a goto statement!  The things you learn on StackExchange.  (I can't remember the last time I wished for a goto statement capability, it doesn't seem to ever come up).

Comment: IMHO it really depends on your "programming religion" and current moonphase. For me (and most people around me) its fine to use a goto to get out of deep nests if the loop is rather small, and the alternative would be a superfluous check of a bool variable introduced just to have the loop condition break. This more so when you want to break out halfway through the body, or when after the innermost loop there is some code that would need to check the bool too.

Comment: @JohnWu `goto` is actually required in a C# switch to fall-through to another case after executing any code inside the first case.  That is the only case I have used goto, though.

Comment: Really?  I can't believe C# wouldn't let it just fall through; that case might actually justify them.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The apparent need for a go-to statement arises from **you choosing poor conditional expressions for the loops**.

You state that you wanted the outer loop to continue as long `i < 10` and the innermost one to continue as long as `j > 0`.

**But in reality that's not what you wanted**, you simply didn't tell the loops the real condition you wanted them to evaluate, then you want to solve it by using break or goto.

**If you tell the loops your true intentions to begin with**, then no need for breaks or goto.

```
bool alsoThis = true;
for (i = 0; i < 10 && alsoThis; i++)
{    
    for (j = 10; j > 0 && alsoThis; j--)
    {
        if (j == i)
        {
            alsoThis = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See my comments on the other answers. The original code prints `i` at the end of the outer loop, so short-circuiting the increment is important to making the code look 100% equivalent. I'm not saying anything in your answer is wrong, I just wanted to point out that breaking the loop *immediately* was an important aspect of the code.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I don't see any code printing `i` at the end of the outer loop in OP's question.

Comment: OP referenced the code from [my question here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/227979/is-there-a-name-for-the-break-n-construct), but left out that part. I didn't downvote you, BTW. The answer is entirely correct in regard to correctly choosing loop conditions.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I guess if you really really really really want to justify a goto, you can device a problem that needs one, on the other hand, I've been programming professionally for two decades and haven't a single real world problem that *needs* one.

Comment: The purpose of the code was not provide a valid use case for `goto` (I'm sure there are better ones), even if it spawned a question which seems to use it as such, but to illustrate the basic action of `break(n)` in languages which didn't support it.

Answer (score 33):

In this instance, you could refactor the code into a separate routine, and then just `return` from the inner loop. That would negate the need to break out of the outer loop:

```
bool isBroken() {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 10; j > 0; j--)
            if (j == i) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Which is to say that yes, what you show is a needlessly complex way to break from nested loops, but no, there is a way to refactor that doesn't make a goto more appealing.

Comment: Just a side note: in the original code it prints `i` after the end of the outer loop. So to really reflect that `i` is the important value, here the `return true;` and `return false;` should both be `return i;`.

Comment: +1, was just about to post this answer, and believe this should be the accepted answer. I can't believe the accepted answer got accepted because that method only works for a specific subset of nested loop algorithms, and doesn't necessarily make the code much cleaner. The method in this answer works generally.

Answer (score 6):

No, I don't think a `goto` is necessary. If you write it like this:

```
bool broken = false;
saved_i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10 && !broken; i++)
{
    broken = false;
    for (j = 10; j > 0 && !broken; j--)
    {
        if (j == i)
        {
            broken = true;
            saved_i = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Having `&&!broken` on both loops lets you break out of both loops when `i==j`.

To me, this approach is preferable. The loop conditions are extremely clear: `i<10 && !broken`.

A working version can be seen here: http://rextester.com/KFMH48414

Code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    boolean broken = false;
    for (i = 0; i < 10 && !broken; i++)
    {
        broken = false;
        for (j = 10; j > 0 && !broken; j--)
        {
            if (j == i)
            {
                broken = true;
                System.out.println("loop breaks when i==j=="+i);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

Output:

```
loop breaks when i==j==1
2
0
```

Comment: Why do you even use `broken` in your first example *at all*?  Just use break on the inner loop. Also, if you absolutely must use `broken`, why declare it outside the loops? Just declare it *inside* the `i` loop. As for the `while` loop, please don't use that. I honestly think it manages to be even **less** readable than the goto version.

Comment: @luiscubal: A variable named `broken` is used because I don't like using the `break` statement (except in switch-case, but that's about it). It's declared outside the outer loop in case you want to break ALL loops when `i==j`. You're right, in general, `broken` only needs to be declared before the outermost loop that it will break.

Comment: In your update, `i==2` at the end of the loop. The success condition should also short-circuit the increment if it is to be 100% equivalent to a `break 2`.

Comment: I personally prefer `broken = (j == i)` rather than the if and, if the language allows it, putting the broken declaration inside the outer loop initialisation. Though it's hard to say these things for this specific example, as the entire loop is a no-op (it returns nothing and has no side effects) and if it does something, it possibly does that inside the if (though I still like `broken = (j ==i); if broken { something(); }` better personally)

Comment: @Martijn In my original code it prints `i` after the end of the outer loop. In other words the only *really* important think is when exactly it breaks out of the outer loop.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: I've added a bit of code to save the value of `i` when `i==j` before the next i-loop increment.

Comment: Adding a flag to a program is semantically equivalent to having two "parallel" copies of the code--one in which the flag is false and the other in which it is true--and jumping between them whenever the flag is set or cleared.  Flags can be useful if they avoid code duplication, but semantically they're even worse than gotos.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "it depends". I advocate to choose regarding legibility and understandability  of your code. The goto way might be more legible than tweaking the condition, or vice versa. You might also take into account least surprise principle, guideline used in the shop/project and consistency of the code base. For instance, goto to leave switch or for error handling is a common practice in the Linux kernel code base. Also note that some programmers might have problems reading your code (either raised with the "goto is evil" mantra, or just not learned because their teacher think so) and a few of them might even "judge you".

Generally speaking, a goto going further in the same function is often acceptable, especially if the jump is not too long. Your use case of leaving a nested loop is one of the known example of "not so evil" goto.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, goto is enough of an improvement that it looks tempting, but it's not so much of  an improvement that it's worth breaking the rule against using them in your code base.

Think of your future reviewer:  s/he will have to think, "Is this person a bad coder or is this in fact a case where the goto was worth it? Let me take 5 minutes to decide this for myself or research it on the internet." Why on earth would you do that to your future coder when you can not use goto entirely?

In general this mentality applies to all "bad" code and even defines it:  if it works now, and is good in this case, but creates effort to verify it's correct, which in this era a goto will always do, then don't do it.

That being said, yes, you produced one of the slightly thornier cases. You may:

- use more complex control structures, like a boolean flag, to break out of both loops
- put your inside loop inside its own routine (likely ideal)
- put both loops in a routine and return instead of breaking

It's very hard for me to create a case where a double-loop isn't so cohesive that it shouldn't be its own routine anyway.

By the way, the best discussion of this I've seen is Steve McConnell's *Code Complete*. If you enjoy thinking of these problems critically I strongly recommend reading, even cover-to-cover despite its immensity.

Comment: It's our job programmers to read and understand code.  Not just simplistic code unless that is the nature of your codebase.  There are, and will always be exceptions to the generality (not rule) against using gotos because of the understood cost.  Whenever the benefit outweighs the cost is when goto should be used; as is the case for all coding decisions in software engineering.

Comment: @dietbuddha there is cost in violating accepted software coding conventions that should be adequately taken into account. There is cost in increasing the diversity of control structures used in a program even if this control structure may be a good fit for a situation. There is cost in breaking static analysis of code. If this is all still worth it then who am I to argue.

Answer (score 1):

**TLD;DR:** No in specific, yes in general

For the specific example you used I would say no for the same reasons many other have pointed out.  You can easily refactor the code into an equivalently good form which eliminates the need for the `goto`.

In general the proscription against `goto` is a generality based on the understood nature of `goto` and the cost of using it.  Part of software engineering is making implementation decisions.  Justification of those decisions occurs by weighing the cost against the benefits and whenever the benefits outweigh the cost the implementation is justified.  Controversy arises because of different valuations, both of cost and benefit.

The point is there will always be exceptions where a `goto` is justified, but only for some because of different valuations.  The pity is many engineers simply exclude techniques in purposeful ignorance because they read it on the internet rather than taking the time to understand why.

Comment: Can you recommend any articles on the goto statement further explaining the cost?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this case justifies an exception, as this can be written as:

```
def outerLoop(){
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if( broken?(i) )
          return; // broken
    }
}

def broken?(i){
   for (j = 10; j > 0; j--) {
        if (j == i) {
            return true; // broken
        }
   }
   return false; // not broken
}
```